# How to partition an int with unique numbers

Tags: c

I am using this algorithm to partition (1<<N)-1, given N. This is the code :

```
void btrack(int k, int N, int sum, int used, int rep) {
    //if (k > (N + 1)) exit(-1);
    //printf("called with k = %d, N = %d, sum = %d, used = %d, rep = %d\n", k, N, sum, used, rep);
    
    if (sum == (1 << N) - 1) {
        printf("ended with %d \n", rep);
        return;
    }
    if ((sum > (1 << N) - 1) || (used & 1 << k))
        return;
    used |= (1 << k);

    for (int i = 1; i <= (1 << N) - 1; i++) {
        if (!(used & 1 << i))
            btrack(i, N, sum + i, used, rep * 10 + i);
    }
}
```

I do not want a regular partition. The numbers in the partition must be unique.
Quick example :

```
N = 3 -> (1<<N)-1 = 7
the Valid answers are :
1 + 2 + 4 = 7
2 + 5 = 7
6 + 1 = 7
4 + 3 = 7
7 = 7

the likes of :
2 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 7
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 3 = 7
etc...
are all incorrect because some numbers are repeated
```

I thought I implemented that logic, but the results are disappointing. I sometimes get sums larger than the goal, and repetitions.

the `rep` variable will hold the numbers used for the sum :
`123` for `1+2+3`  or `25` for `2+5`

thank you

Comment: 1+2+3 is not 7.

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to include exact cases where code does not work and ideally your debugging attempts. Also when adding tags please read they descriptions carefullly and avoid adding non-specific tags like "math" or unrelated "partitioning" (as you are not really separating datasets).

Comment: Your question is not self-consistent. In the 1st line of text you write "(N<<1)-1", but in a code block lower down you write "(1<<N)-1". Please fix whichever is the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mis-using your variable `k`. That appears to hold the last value that you tried to test. The nature of recursion is that you are trying to break the problem down into smaller problems, so if you want to avoid repetition, then you should never use that same value in a recursive call.

Instead, begin the loop at `k+1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void btrack(int k, int N, int sum, int used, int rep) {
    if (sum == (1 << N) - 1) {
        printf("ended with %d \n", rep);
        return;
    }
    if ((sum > (1 << N) - 1) || (used & 1 << k))
        return;
    used |= (1 << k);

    for (int i = k+1; i <= (1 << N) - 1; i++) {
        btrack(i, N, sum + i, used, rep * 10 + i);
    }
}

int main() {
    btrack(0, 3, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Output:

```
ended with 124 
ended with 16 
ended with 25 
ended with 34 
ended with 7
```

Now, this all works until you need to partition really large values. Your base-10 `rep` value becomes useless almost immediately, and your `used` value runs out of bits. And when you want to actually *print* a result you will need to search through a bit-array consisting of mostly zeroes.

An alternative solution is to store the path in an array. It might look something like this (semi-robust but a little naive):

```
int run_foo(int value, int sum_parts[], int max_count, int count)
{
    if (count + 1 >= max_count)
        return 0;

    // Loop over all potential next values
    for (int next = sum_parts[count] + 1; next <= value / 2; next++) {
        sum_parts[count + 1] = next;
        if (!run_foo(value - next, sum_parts, max_count, count + 1))
            return 0;
    }

    // Print result
    if (sum_parts[count] < value) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            printf("%d + ", sum_parts[i]);
        }
        printf("%d\n", value);
    }
    return 1;
}

int foo(int value, int sum_parts[], int max_count)
{
    if (max_count < 1)
        return 0;
    sum_parts[0] = 0;
    return run_foo(value, sum_parts, max_count, 0);
}

int main()
{
    const int max_count = 10;
    int sum_parts[max_count];
    foo(15, sum_parts, max_count);
}
```

Output:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
1 + 2 + 3 + 9
1 + 2 + 4 + 8
1 + 2 + 5 + 7
1 + 2 + 12
1 + 3 + 4 + 7
1 + 3 + 5 + 6
1 + 3 + 11
1 + 4 + 10
1 + 5 + 9
1 + 6 + 8
1 + 14
2 + 3 + 4 + 6
2 + 3 + 10
2 + 4 + 9
2 + 5 + 8
2 + 6 + 7
2 + 13
3 + 4 + 8
3 + 5 + 7
3 + 12
4 + 5 + 6
4 + 11
5 + 10
6 + 9
7 + 8
15
```

Here, an array is used to store the path to the current value, and the recursive call tries to build a value out of whatever remains by using only values larger than the last one used. This uses a bit more memory, but the performance should scale much better.

Note that since the array is essentially a stack, you could probably implement this solution without needing recursion at all, with a little bit of extra care. That's a perfect *"Exercise for the Reader"*.

Comment: Thank you for this precise and complete answer, i wish i asked before submitting my work. This was the only thing missing

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems:

- `rep * 10 + i` can only store single digit numbers. For `N=4` you cannot represent `1+15` or `2+14`, etc.
- `used |= (1 << k);` is limited by the range of the `int` type. for `N` greater than `4`, `k` can be larger than 30, hence `1 << k` would have undefined behavior.

Your approach might work for `N < 4` but a more general approach is needed for larger values.  I suggest using an array. This array needs to hold at most `sqrt(1 << N)` numbers, hence `1 << (N - 1)` numbers.